# SQL Start and END Dates and rows transformations

Tags: sql

```
                            START                          END
'event'             '2018-06-11'    to     '2018-06-12'  
'event'             '2018-06-13'    to     '2018-06-16'     
'event'             '2018-06-19'    to     '2018-06-20'      
'event'             '2018-06-23'    to     '2018-06-25'      
'event'             '2018-06-27'    to     '2018-06-28'      
'event'             '2018-06-29'    to     '2018-06-30'
```

I have this table and I want transform it like this using SQL Statements :

```
                      START                           END
'event'             '2018-06-11'    to     '2018-06-12'       row1
'event'             '2018-06-13'    to     '2018-06-16'       row1
'event'             '2018-06-19'    to     '2018-06-20'       row2
'event'              2018-06-23'    to     '2018-06-25'       row3
'event'             '2018-06-27'    to     '2018-06-28'       row4
'event'             '2018-06-29'    to     '2018-06-30'       row4
```

this should become a table of 4 rows.

So the logic behind is : 
When the next row represent continuity of  the row before, it means they should be in the same line and 
the start_date should be the beginning of this row and the end date should become the end of this continuity.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Please use a text editor that consistently inserts tabs or spaces when you press Tab..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DBMS supports window functions, you can use `lag()` to check the difference of the previous end to the current start. If it's less than or equal to 1 record a `0` else a `1`. Then use cumulative `sum()` to add these values.

```
SELECT *,
       'row' || sum("not_a_follow_up") OVER (ORDER BY "start",
                                                      "end")
       FROM (SELECT *,
                    CASE
                      WHEN "start" - lag("end") OVER (ORDER BY "start",
                                                               "end") <= 1 THEN
                        0
                      ELSE
                        1
                    END "not_a_follow_up"
                    FROM "elbat") "x";
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=1ccbcc7a46735f961a136009c31707c2)